# How to use a variable in two classes?

Tags: java

I need to be able to see in all of these classes if the variable is `true`.

```
    public void performAction() {
    if (door.intersects(HERO)) {
        System.out.println("ActionPerformed!");
        HeroX = 0;
        HeroY = 0;
        inside = true;
        }
    }
```

This is every time I press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and now I want to draw the inside of the House.
In the Main class where I draw everything I want to say something like:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (!inside) {
        g.drawImage(Background, 0, 0, null);
        achilles.Draw(g);
    }else if (inside) {
        g.drawImage(HouseInside, 0, 0, null);
         }
    }
```

I don't know how to change the "inside" in the Hero class and use it in the Main class. I have tried so many things and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you looking for a shared variable or a global state variable? Both can accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**inside** is a property of a HERO object, so, if the property is public, you can access it with heroname.inside

If the property is private (which it generally should be), you have to use a public access function inside the HERO class, such as HERO.isInside, and set it with a setting function like HERO.setInside and HERO.setOutside.

this is often called "getters and setters"

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want are global variables

```
public class Global{
    public static int value;
}
```

You can then access them from anywhere:

```
Global.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Main class has a reference to all instances of the Hero class, then the usual best practice would be for the Hero class to expose a method like this:

```
public boolean isInside () {
    return (inside);
}
```

If there is only ever one instance of the Hero class (unlikely, but ok), then one option is to make inside a public static variable like this:

```
public static boolean inside;
```

referenced from Main like this:

```
if (! Hero.inside) {
```

or make inside a private static variable with a getter like this:

```
private static boolean inside;

public static boolean isInside () {
    return (inside);
}
```

referenced from Main like this:

```
if (! Hero.isInside ()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a getter to get the `inside` attribute outside of `Hero`, and a setter to change it:

```
public class Hero {
    private boolean inside;

    ...        

    public boolean isInside() {
        return this.inside;
    }

    public void setInside(boolean inside) {
        this.inside = inside;
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend reading more about [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29); it'll give you a better idea about how to work with objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could model it differently:

```
public class House {

    Location currentLocation=Location.OUTSIDE;

    Map<Location, String> layout=new HashMap<>();

    public House(){
        layout.put(Location.INSIDE,"Draw the inner parts");
        layout.put(Location.INSIDE,"Draw the outer parts");
    }

    public void enterDoor(){
        currentLocation=(currentLocation==Location.OUTSIDE)?Location.INSIDE:Location.OUTSIDE;
    }

    public void draw(){

        System.out.println(layout.get(currentLocation));

    }

}
```

Here `enterDoor` is something, which could be fired by an event in your game-environment. So your House knows how to draw itself depending on its state.

Say your character moves to some coordinates (*x*|*y*), where the door is, the `enterDoor`is called upon `House`, which in turn switches the layout.